# Javascript - querying object property value

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to query a range of objects for a specific value before you do anything with it? For example, I will be getting a JSON structure similar to below with a set of properties:

```
"Properties": [
  {
    "Name": "product",
    "Values": [ "Jacket", "Shirt", "Trousers" ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "color",
    "Values": [ "Red", "Blue", "Green" ]
  }
]
```

Once I've loaded the JSON in my JS, I would like to be able to ask something like "go through each object in the array - if Name equals 'product', do something, if Name equals 'color', do something else" and so on.

I was thinking it would be something similar to the below, but so far no luck. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to query a value in a child of Properties.

```
if (Properties.hasOwnProperty('Name') === "product") {
    alert('Yes');
} else {
    alert('No');
}
```

Predictably, the above snippet is returning "No" even when a Name property has the value "product".

Comment: Hint:  `Properties` is an array of objects which have `Name` property. Just loop over them

Comment: `Properties.hasOwnProperty('Name') === "product"` will always be false, as `hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to ask something like "go through each object in the array - if Name equals 'product', do something, if Name equals 'color', do something else" and so on.

You're describing a loop, and then branching within the loop. There are a dozen ways to loop through an array in JavaScript ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) covers most if not all of them). One of those is `forEach`.

For the branch, you'd typically use `if` or `switch` although there are many options for that, too.

So for instance, **one possible** way is to use `forEach` and `switch`:

```
Properties.forEach(function(property) {
    switch (property.Name) {
        case "product":
            // ...
            break;
        case "color":
            // ...
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Seabizkit: There's no particular reason for the overhead of adding that `hasOwnProperty` call. All of the OP's objects have it, and the effect of *not* having it is just that it doesn't match anything in the `switch` (not, for instance, an error).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (pure js):

```
Properties = [
    {
        "Name": "product",
        "Values": [ "Jacket", "Shirt", "Trousers" ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "color",
        "Values": [ "Red", "Blue", "Green" ]
   }
];
for (i = 0; i < Properties.length; i++) { 
    var p = Properties[i];
    if (p.hasOwnProperty('Name') && p.Name == "product") {
        console.log('Yes');
    } else {
        console.log('No');
    }
}
```